# Does Google BigQuery and Google cloud storage share files between them?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have created a BigQuery table by loading CSV file from Google cloud storage.

In this case, does BigQuery table reference the CSV file in cloud storage or it copies data to its own storage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you load file from Cloud Storage to BigQuery - this loads data into BigQuery "own" storage that is totally different from Cloud Storage.

Note: BigQuery supports querying data directly from Google Cloud Storage and Google Drive.  See details at [Creating and Querying Federated Data Sources](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/federated-data-sources)